# Confusions over linear algebra related details over vector space $c_0$

Tags: functional-analysis

For the following question:

Let $c_0$ be the collection of all sequences $(x_k)$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} x_k=0$.  It is straightforward to verify that the usual operations of pointwise addition and scalar multiplication, $c_0$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.  Let $e_{k}=(0,...,0,1,0,...0)$. (1 in the i-th place and 0 otherwise) Is $\mathcal{B}=\{e_{k}: k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ a basis for $c_0$?$

I want to ask if

1. Am I correct to think that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $c_0$?.
2. Does $c_0?$ consist elements of the form: $\{x_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ where $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} x_k=0$?
3. If $\{x_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ is consider to be elements of $c_0$, then how can it be written as a finite linear combination of elements from $\mathcal{B}$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. As you correctly get doubts in 3., this is **not** a basis.
2. This is just the definition.
3. You only get *eventually zero* sequences by finite linear combinations.

Comment: can a sequence with elements that are eventually zero can serve as a basis for $c_0$?

Comment: @SethMai No, by the same reason.

Comment: can I ask, since $c_0$ is an example of a sequence space and it forms a vector space. What does a basis for $c_0$ look like, or are there something even called a standard basis like we have for $R^n$.  Also, because elements of $c_0$ are sequences, each consist of infinite number of elements.  So if i take an arbitrary element of $c_0$, in essence an arbitrary sequence, can it be written as a finite linear combination of elements of the basis for $c_0$.  I know there are something call Hamel and Schuader basis.  But I am not that familar with the finer details of either of those topics.

Comment: The standard basis sequences you wrote do form a *Schauder* basis, where countably infinite linear combinations are also enabled, but a normal (Hamel) basis must contain more elements, and there isn't a standard choice for that: its existence requires (some form of) the axiom of choice.